# How to remove the previous screen in the parent navigator?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Environment

react-navigation@3.11.1 | 
react-navigation-stack@1.4.0

Given the following React Navigation

```
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const TutorialNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    FirstScreen: ({ navigation }) => { },
    SecondScreen: ({ navigation }) => { },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'FirstScreen',
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeNavigator: createStackNavigator(
      {
        FirstScreen: ({ navigation }) => { },
        SecondScreen: ({ navigation }) => { },
        ThirdScreen: ({ navigation }) => { },
        FourthScreen: ({ navigation }) => { },
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'FirstScreen',
      }
    ),
    ProfileNavigator: createStackNavigator({
      FirstScreen: ({ navigation }) => { },
      SecondScreen: ({ navigation }) => { },
    }, {
      initialRouteName: 'FirstScreen',
    }),
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    TutorialNavigator,
    AppNavigator,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AppNavigator',
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
  }
);

const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainNavigator,
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'MainStackNavigator',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      RootNavigator,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Root',
    }
  )
);
```

Performing the following navigation:

```
RootNavigator -> MainNavigator -> AppNavigator -> HomeNavigator -> FirstScreen -> SecondScreen -> ThirdScreen
```

followed by

```
TutorialNavigator -> FirstScreen -> SecondScreen
```

followed by

```
HomeNavigator -> FourthScreen
```

If I initiate a back navigation, from the FourthScreen of the HomeNavigator, I will end up on the ThirdScreen of the HomeNavigator (the navigation of the first line), because the TutorialNavigator's stack was removed once I navigated away from it.

Question:

How can I navigate from the SecondScreen of the TutorialNavigator (the second line) to the FourthScreen of the HomeNavigator and remove the ThirdScreen from the history, i.e. when I go back from the FourthScreen, I don't want to end up on the ThirdScreen, but I want to end up on the SecondScreen of the HomeNavigator?

Since the use case constrains the navigation to be initiated from the TutorialNavigators' screens to the FourthScreen of the HomeNavigator, here are my working attempts that yield an inconsistent behaviour from the animation point of view:

1st:

```
const parentNavigation = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();

const goHome = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Home',
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'FirstScreen'
  })
});

const goToHomeFourthScreen = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'FourthScreen',
  params: { subscriptionKey }
});

parentNavigation.dispatch(goHome);
parentNavigation.dispatch(goToHomeFourthScreen);
```

2nd

```
navigation.dismiss();

parentNavigation.reset({
  routeName: 'FourthScreen',
  params: { subscriptionKey }
});
```

Not working:

```
parentNavigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.reset({
    key: 'AppNavigator',
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'HomeNavigator'
      }),
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'FourthScreen'
      })
    ]
  })
);
```

Any attempts to dispatch a reset with multiple actions fails or has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a stack navigator, that is a sibling of a tab navigator, how can I issue a history reset for the tab navigator, or more precisely for a child (which is a stack navigator) of the tab navigator?

So far, this is the only way I've managed to make it work, but it's less than ideal

```
/**
  Issuing this from the FirstScreen of the TutorialNavigator
*/

const goToHome = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'HomeNavigator',
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'FirstScreen'
  })
});

const goToHomeFourthScreen = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'FourthScreen'
});

navigation.dispatch(goToHome);
navigation.dispatch(goToHomeFourthScreen);
```

This is taking advantage of the fact that the FirstScreen is the first screen of the stack navigator in the tab navigator, hence providing a clean history where we can push new screens onto.

Though this solution still does not provide a smooth animation, it dismisses the stacked navigator, shows the HomeNavigator's FirstScreen and then navigates to the HomeNavigator's FourthScreen. Can't we have the navigation animation happen only on the last dispatch?